# Extending pgfornament's vector lines on the entire line width

Tags: rules, pgfornament

There are nice looking ornaments for horizontal lines in pgfornament ([see page 20 of this doc](http://mirrors.concertpass.com/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/tkz/pgfornament/doc/ornaments.pdf)).

However, the length of the left and right straight parts of some of these ornaments is quite short. Looking at ornament 88, I ideally want something like this:

[image]

That is, having this ornament centered horizontally, where the left and right straight parts of the ornament are stretched to fill the rest of the line.

I have the following command to arrive to this result, using the `xhfill` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[object=vectorian]{pgfornament}
\usepackage{xhfill}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\separator}{%
  { 
    \noindent\xhrulefill{black}{1.39pt}
    \hspace{-13pt}
    \raisebox{-2.95pt}{\resizebox{0.4\linewidth}{2ex}
    {{
    {\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node  (C) at (0,0) {};
    \node (D) at (6,0) {};
    \path (C) to [ornament=88] (D);
    \end{tikzpicture}}}}}}%
    \hspace{-13pt}
    \xhrulefill{black}{1.39pt}
  }

\begin{document}

\separator

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

This works OK as you can see, but it has some problems:

- Lines are superimposed on the ornament which leads to graphical bugs when viewing the PDF in pdf viewers, depending on the zooming level (a common problem).
- The width of the `xhrulefill` is not exactly right; I can see a very slight difference when printing this on a page. I can't seem to make it disappear no matter how close I get to the "correct" width.
- (this command's code is ugly, but that's a minor problem)

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is probably best do all the drawing inside `tikz`.  You can get the total width required from `\textwidth`.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[object=vectorian]{pgfornament}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\separator}{%
  {\par\noindent
  \begin{tikzpicture}\def\mylen{3cm}
    \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (C) at (\mylen,0);
    \coordinate (B) at (\textwidth,0);
    \coordinate (D) at ($(\textwidth,0)-(\mylen,0)$);
    \draw[line width=1.15pt,line cap=rect] ($(A)+.5*(1.15pt,0)$) -- (C) (D) -- ($(B)-.5*(1.15pt,0)$);
    \path (C) to[ornament=88, options/.append style={yshift=.52pt}] (D);
    \end{tikzpicture}}
  }

\begin{document}

\separator

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

The lines have a width close to `1pt` at this scale but not centered on the axis, hence the `yshift` gymnastics.  You will have to adjust the values `1.15pt` for the line thickness and `.52pt` for the y shift according to the value of `\mylen` and `\textwidth` to get things to match.

Comment: Wouldn't the first coordinate of `B` rather be `\textwidth - 1.15`? I seem to get an overfull hbox otherwise.

Comment: @Fatalize Thank you, I had overlooked the overfull box.  It is better to shorten at both ends by half this amount to preserve symmetry.  Code now modified.