# How to make vector lines wider but not higher

Tags: pgfornament

I want to have the vector lines 1 and 2 with that height but with straight lines a bit longer.

I've found a workaround [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/394204/extending-pgfornaments-vector-lines-on-the-entire-line-width) but as you can see in the snippet the lines don't line up.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,article,oneside]{memoir}


\usepackage{pgfornament}
\usepackage{tikz} %draw circles, squares, etc.
%\usepackage{caption} %change caption style
\usetikzlibrary{calc}


\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
    paper=a4paper,
    top=3.5cm,
    bottom=3.5cm,
    left=3cm,
    right=3cm,
}




\begin{document}


1) 

\begin{center}
\pgfornament[scale=.35, width=5cm]{89}
\end{center}




2) 

\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node (A) at (0,0) {};
        \node (B) at (5,0) {}; 
        \pgfornamentline{A}{B}{1}{88} 
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}





3) 

\begin{tikzpicture}\def\mylen{3cm}
    \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (C) at (\mylen,0);
    \coordinate (B) at (\textwidth,0);
    \coordinate (D) at ($(\textwidth,0)-(\mylen,0)$);
    \draw[line width=1.15pt,line cap=rect] ($(A)+.5*(1.15pt,0)$) -- (C) (D) -- ($(B)-.5*(1.15pt,0)$);
    \path (C) to[ornament=88, options/.append style={yshift=.52pt}] (D);
    \end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

[image: snippet of three line vectors]

Comment: It does not line up because the document classes are not the same, i.e. the `\textwidth`s differ. The solution you link to is very tuned, `yshift=.52pt`, and if you change a detail it won't work.

Comment: I didn't understand the code so I didn't know what I needed to adjust. Now I know and can adjust myself. Which part do I adjust to get a thinner line?